# EclipseLink JPQL query with MEMBER OF operator

Tags: jpa, eclipselink, jpql

Here is my example:

*Department entity*

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "DEPART_TABLE")
public class Department {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private Long departmentId;

    @Column(name = "NAME")
    private String departmentName;

    @Column(name = "POST_NO")
    private String postNumber;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "department")
    private List<Employee> employees;

    // getters/setters
}
```

*Employee entity*

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "EMPL_TABLE")
public class Employee {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "USER_NO")
    private String userNumber;

    @Column(name = "NAME")
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "EMAIL")
    private String email;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "DEP_ID")
    private Department department;

    // getters/setters
}
```

Basically, I have a department with a list of employees. At some point, I need to `find` a department having only `userNumber`. The service for this looks like:

```
public Department getDepartment(String userNumber) { 
    //JPQL query here to find a department by employee.userName
}
```

There is a relationship between these two entities, so the easiest way would be probably `entityManager.find(Employee.class, userNumber)` and afterward just call `employee.getDepartment()` on the returned entity. This works fine.

But is there any other way to do this? It looks like EclipseLink `MEMBER OF` could be used:

```
SELECT d FROM Department d WHERE '<????>' MEMBER OF d.employees
```

Is it possible to create a JPQL query to find the department I need, using this operator, or something else like `JOIN`?

Answer (score 1):

You do not need `JOIN` or `MEMBER` since `Department` is a direct field of `Employee`. You just have a bit wrong aspect. Do it like:

```
String query = 
        "SELECT e.department FROM Employee e WHERE e.userNumber=:userNumber";
```

and use like:

```
TypedQuery<Department> tq = em.createQuery(query, Department.class);
Department d = tq.setParameter("userNumber", "2401").getSingleResult();
```

Update: just to stress thate the passed parameter should correspond the value compared - so `MEMBER OF` needs an `Employee` entity, you cannot twist `userNumber` to that easily - and to show how it would go with (and noting that these queries are a bit dim and not to be used in this way...):

**MERGE**

```
    String query = " SELECT d FROM Department d, Employee e "
        + " WHERE e.userNumber=:userNumber AND e MEMBER OF d.employees ";
```

**MERGE + JOIN**

```
String query = " SELECT d FROM Department d JOIN d.employees e "
        + "WHERE e.userNumber=:userNumber AND e MEMBER OF d.employees ";
```